# WebStorm/IDEA support for angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, plugins, internationalization, webstorm

Our team is new to AngularJs, and we use angular-translate to do the I18N job. We store I18N info in json file.

In our HTML files, we need to write codes like `{{'code'|translate}}` for angular-translate to recognize label or something needs to be translated. Sometimes the code could be too long to read.

HTML:

```
<th>{{'finance.label.fundCode'|translate}}</th>
<th>{{'finance.label.fundName'|translate}}</th>
<th>{{'finance.label.fundNetValue'|translate}}</th>
<th>{{'finance.label.returnRate3m'|translate}}</th>
```

json:

```
  "finance.label.fundCode":"基金代码",
  "finance.label.fundName":"基金名称",
  "finance.label.fundNetValue":"基金净值",
  "finance.label.returnRate3m":"近3月收益率",
```

I'm wondering is there is a way to display I18N translation in HTML files, just like IntelliJ IDEA doing in Spring configuration files. They call it code folding, I don't know if I can customise code folding format and source for this usage scenario.

Expectation:

```
<th>基金代码</th>
<th>基金名称</th>
<th>基金净值</th>
<th>近3月收益率</th>
```

I expect my IDE can display I18N info right in the HTML files without changing the real code, and when I focus or hover the code segment, it would show the origin code.

I would like to develop a plugin to achieve this, but I'm not sure if a plugin can do such thing. If someone knows IDEA/WebStorm plugin can do something like this, I am very willing to give a try.

Also I'd like to know any way to get similar result.